# How do I add a search box to the nav menu?

Tags: menus

I would like to add a search box to the nav menu by appending the following code in `functions.php` (at the end of the file, but before `?>`).

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2 );
function add_search_box( $items, $args ) {
    $items .= '<li>' . get_search_form( false ) . '</li>';
    return $items;
}
```

However, the search box doesn't appear.

---

**EDIT**: Actually, there is no problem with the above code. While clicking the search icon (PS: the theme I use is [Radiate](https://wordpress.org/themes/radiate/)), two search boxes appear.

**What I expect is to place the search box inside the nav menu**, instead of a click is needed to show the search box:

[image]

PS: here is the `searchform.php`:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _ex( 'Search for:', 'label', 'radiate' ); ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'radiate' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" name="s">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'radiate' ); ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: You can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-search-to-menu to achieve it.

Comment: @VinodDalvi, thx. looks interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me as is. The only thing I can think of is that you have a searchform.php defined in your theme but it's empty?  (If searchform.php doesn't exist in your theme, WP will use a default form.)

Comment: Thx. Yeah, no problem with the above code. I update my question, please check it.

Comment: Okay that sounds like a theme behavior issue - have you tried looking through searchform.php for the html elements, and the themes css rules that apply to the form? You'll probably just have to edit those directly.

Comment: thx again. I paste the code of `searchform.php` to the question.

Comment: You seem to be fishing for someone to do your work for you. The search field is being rendered, so your original question is resolved. Now you're just dealing with css/javascript behaviour issues that have very little to do with wordpress. If you have no idea where to start, you should hire a developer to help you.

Comment: thx for ur kind reminder.